# Check if the user has read a node, if so give access to the next

Tags: 8

Is there a module which can check if an user has read a node? For example, I have this node:

1. Node order 1
2. Node order 2 (locked)
3. Node order 3 (locked)
4. Node order 4 (locked)

If the user read 'node order 1' or marked as read with a button, he has access to 'node order 2'. If 'node order 2' has marked as read, he has access to 'node order 3'.

It's all user based. It's similar to an e-learning structure, but I don't like heavy modules like: course or opigno for just this functionality.

Can I do something like this with rules or an other lightweight module? I saw the flag module, but I don't know if it possible to do something like this with that module?

Comment: Rules isnt exactly lightweight. I think you need at a minimum a table to hold nid/uid/read values, and create an entry when the node is viewed. On each node, add a reference field to hold the required node to read, and evaluate that too when viewing a node. It's probably not too hard to pull off.

Comment: What about the size of the table? If 1000 users each viewing 500 nodes I've a table with: 500.000 entries? Any ideas?

Comment: May be , Once the user has read all the nodes, deleted the entries in the table and set a new field with value stating user has read all nodes ?
So that you have only one entry per user if user has read all.

Comment: Yes, that could be one solution. Doing multiple writes shouldn't be too big of a deal. You'd have the same issue if 1000 users clicked a button that inserted records too. The size of the table doesn't necessarily matter, use good indices. There's probably a few ways to mitigate that, the scope of the question would need more focus to answer any one part in depth.

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that they've viewed node 1 before viewing node 2? or is it more like a recommendation?

Comment: It's an hard requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you can use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.9.x) to store the uid and the nid of the user into a custom table. That would solve the easy part, I believe.

You'd may start by something similar to

```
function yourmodule_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, 
        \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  $bundle = $entity->bundle();
  if($bundle == 'your_content_type') {
    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id(); // get current user's ID
    $nid = $entity->get('nid');
    [...] // insert into custom table, etc
  }
}
```

For the long-term, complex solution regarding performance, that's a huge discussion. If your node list is just a simple queue that unlocks next node if previous has been read, then maybe storing just the current nid would work for you. If you need the history per user, then, as mentioned, some different solutions could do the trick. Other approach could be to do database sharding, for instance creating 1 table per node so table_read_nid_1 would just contain the users who actually have read this node and can unlock the second. table_read_nid_2 would contain the next and so on. Don't be afraid of sharding, lots of big companies use it daily! :)

Comment: Could you give me an example of the code: `hook_entity_type_view`?

Comment: Edited to add an initial snippet you could look at to start using the hook.